# how should the sixth question be answered

Tags: determinant

Prove that

$$\begin{vmatrix}a+b & b+c & c+a\\l+m & m+n & n+l\\p+q & q+r & r+p\end{vmatrix}\div \begin{vmatrix}a & b & c\\l & m & n\\p & q & r\end{vmatrix} = 2$$

I have tried solving this after expanding it fully but i cant seem to find an answer.

Comment: the question is to prove that the given can be resolved into two

Comment: I withdrew my comment because I think I misread the question.  The link is somewhat hard to read.  I had read the arithmetic symbol as "$+$" but I expect it really is "$\div$".  You still have to assume that at least the second determinant is non-zero.

Comment: Learn some basic Mathjax for posting here.

Comment: IT asks to do addition

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ l & m & n \\ p & q & r \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} C_1 & C_2 & C_3 \end{pmatrix}$ where $C_i$ is the $i$-th column.

Let $B = \begin{pmatrix} a+b & b+c & c+a \\ l+m & m+n & n+l \\ p+q & q+r & r+p \end{pmatrix}$

Then $B = \begin{pmatrix} C_1 + C_2 & C_2 + C_3 & C_3 + C_1 \end{pmatrix}$

And you're asked to show that $|B| = 2|A|$.

It's quite easy to see that $\begin{pmatrix} C_1+C_2 & C_2+C_3 & C_3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ share the same determinant, now how can you turn $C_3$ into $C_3+C_1$ using the columns $C_1+C_2$ and $C_2+C_3$ ?

Comment: No the question is ratehr A+B=2

Comment: the question is to rather prove A+B=2

Comment: @Joseph_Kandathil No ; $|A | + |B| = 2$ is generally false, as shown by the example $A=I$